# Resolve webpack image source within Vue Component (within Vuepress)

Tags: vue.js, webpack, vuepress

I am using the latest **Vuepress** release (`1.0.0-alpha.46`) and have the docs configured off the root directory and have an `assets` folder where I store all my images.

Referencing these images in markdown is no problem. For instance:

```
![ ](../assets/foobar.jpg)
```

Works just fine even though Webpack is adding an alias to the image of something like `assets/foobar.57589334.jpg`. Sadly, things start to fall over when I use a Vue component in my Vuepress. In this case I'm simply adding this to my markdown file:

```
this is some markdown
<zoom-image src="../assets/foobar.jpg" />
```

But now I'm getting the string literal without webpack's postfix added. I know I *could* put the image into `.vuepress/public` but that seems wrong and may actually cache things in the service worker that I don't want to. In the docs it talks about how you can configure webpack with aliases and I thought I'd give that a try. I configured webpack in the `.vuepress/config.js` file:

```
configureWebpack: {
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      "@images": "assets"
    }
  }
},
```

and the MD is now:

```
this is some markdown
<zoom-image src="~@images/foobar.jpg" />
```

No errors but maybe not surprisingly the string literal was just passed into my component again. I thought maybe I could pull in some sort of export from webpack to force it to transform the image name but I've not gotten anything to work. Can anyone help?

Comment: If You find the way to make it work please let us know

Comment: I'm wondering if you've ever managed to succeed the above? Running into the same issue as we speak.

Answer (score 2):

Heellooooo there, if I got your point, my solution looks like below:
the config.js is:

```js
configureWebpack: {
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      "@assets": path.resolve(__dirname, '../assets')
    }
  }
},
```

and my file structure is:

```
|-- .vuepress
|   |-- config.js
|-- assets
|   |-- icon.png
|-- guide
|   |-- 1.md
|   |-- 2.md
|   |-- 3.md
|   |-- 4.md
```

And then use this alias like: `![icon](~@assets/icon.png)`

Answer (score 1):

If for some reason you are not able to get it working with `configureWebpack` try with `chainWebpack` instead.

```js
const path = require("path"); // Don't forget this

module.exports = {
  chainWebpack: config => {
    config.resolve.alias.set('@assets', path.resolve(__dirname, "../assets"))
  }
}
```

My structure

```
|-- .vuepress
|   |-- config.js
|-- assets
|   |-- foobar.jpg
```

Alias like `![My foobar](~@assets/foobar.jpg)`